# XPATH 1.0 - count the number of times a node appears with same value in an XML doc

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a document that appears like this:

```
<Subdocument Label="Subdocument">
 <Lines Label="Lines">
   <Line>
    <ITEM>AAA</ITEM>
   </Line>
 </Lines>
</Subdocument>

<Subdocument Label="Subdocument">
 <Lines Label="Lines">
   <Line>
    <ITEM>AAA</ITEM>
   </Line>
 </Lines>
</Subdocument>

<Subdocument Label="Subdocument">
 <Lines Label="Lines">
   <Line>
    <ITEM>BBB</ITEM>
   </Line>
 </Lines>
</Subdocument>

<Subdocument Label="Subdocument">
 <Lines Label="Lines">
   <Line>
    <ITEM>BBB</ITEM>
   </Line>
 </Lines>
</Subdocument>
```

Is there a way to write an XPath 1.0 using the count syntax of how many times a repeating value appears in the document? The expected result would be that AAA appeared 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Following XPath expression would do the job:

```
count(.//*[text()='AAA'])
```

But please note, that XML in your example is not syntactically correct ("Subdocument" elements should be wrapped in some root element).

Comment: I should have tried to be more articulate with the problem. Sorry!
The values of the node <ITEM> are unknown to me until a transaction occurs. 

The challenge has been how many times the node <ITEM> appears with the same values repeatedly.

I am starting to think that there is no XPATH 1.0 to address this problem as a single line syntax.

Answer (score 0):

### XPath to select all text nodes in an XML document that...

- exactly equal `"AAA"`:

  ```
  //text()[.="AAA"]
  ```
- exactly equal `"AAA"`, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace:

  ```
  //text()[normalize-space()="AAA"])
  ```
- have `"AAA"` as a substring:

  ```
  //text()[contains(.,"AAA")]
  ```

Any of the above can be wrapped in `count()` to return the number of nodes meeting stated condition.

Comment: I should have tried to be more articulate with the problem. Sorry!
The values of the node <ITEM> are unknown to me until a transaction occurs. 

The challenge has been how many times the node <ITEM> appears with the same values repeatedly.

I am starting to think that there is no XPATH 1.0 to address this problem as a single line syntax.

Comment: Your requirements are (again) lacking.  Do you mean to constrain `ITEM` to only have a single value?  If not, are you asking for the maximum number of `ITEM` elements that have the same value?  The minimum number?   As you can see, you've ***still*** not been clear in expressing what you want.

Comment: "Are you asking for the maximum number of ITEM elements that have the same value?" that is what I am looking for!